# Azure appservices warmup taking forever

Tags: azure, initialization, azure-web-app-service, application-warmup

I am running my asp.net C# app on azure appservices in a reasonably good plan and I am getting a really slow app initialization. This happens every time I deploy or restart the app.

At first, I thought my global.asax Application_Startup was taking too long to load configs from the database. But then I realized that it is taking over 20 mins before it even hits my Application_Startup.

I'm looking for ideas on where to look for the root cause of the problem.

Many thanks

Comment: How are you deploying the app?

Comment: Did you add the following in the web.config file? <applicationInitialization>
  <add initializationPage="/Warmup" />
  </applicationInitialization>

Comment: I'm deploying the app via azure devops pipeline. I've tried using slots but no luck. 
I've also tried using <applicationInitialization /> in the web.config. It only redirects to a warmup page but the warmup time is still over 20 mins.

Comment: If you are familiar with ETW traces you may be able to use the profiling tool to understand where the CPU time is taking place to better understand what's happening. A memory dump of the process could come into handy as well.

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/06/06/App-Service-Diagnostics-Profiling-an-ASP.NET-Web-App-on-Azure-App-Service.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check for Azure Metrics logs to get more details, also one of the best thing which I love to do is remote debugging on Azure app. You can check below post for more details on remote debugging:

[Remote debugging Azure App Service](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/remote-debugging-azure-app-services/)

Comment: I also tried remote debugging, but the problem happens during initialization. So it takes over 20 mins before it even hits my code to debug.